# How do I fix Emmet's code snippets for transition-duration?

Tags: emmet, adobe-brackets

**One of the snippets in Emmet for Brackets is `-transition-duration`. 
When you press tab after it, it's supposed to come up with this:**

```
-webkit-transition-duration: ;
-moz-transition-duration: ;
-ms-transition-duration: ;
-o-transition-duration: ;
transition-duration: ;
```

**However, whenever I use it, all I get is this:**

```
-webkit-transition-duration: ;
-o-transition-duration: ;
transition-duration: ;
```

**The same thing happens with**

```
-transition-delay
```

**and**

```
-transform
```

**I have tried removing and re-adding Emmet, but it didn't work for me.** 
*Could someone please tell me what to do to fix this?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emmet uses Can I Use database to generate vendor prefixes. If you consult this database, you’ll see that there’s no `-ms-transition-duration` at all and `-moz-transition-duration` is supported by <0.1% browsers in a wild.

If you still think you have to use all selectors, you should create your own snipptes as described here: http://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/